# Legal remedies for being banned from a school system

Tags: education, first-amendment, georgia, due-process

I was banned from a school system for providing behavior interventions to students without the administration's approval.  The Board's attorney banned me using a trespassing statute.
I never trespassed since I was asked to come to the teacher's classroom by the teacher. She invited me to mentor students who were having behavior problems.
The principal informed me that the Supt. and Board of Education's Attorney conspired to ban me because the Supt. was upset about a book that I had released and my advocacy work that resulted in the system being taken to court. This is the third year of my ban. I have asked for a hearing, and The Board of Education refuses to give me one. According to one member, their attorney told them that they had to ban me.
What legal remedies are available to me? I have tried to patiently work with the system, but I would not like to litigate the issue. The attorney wrote a letter to my local court informing them of my ban, which resulted in me being removed from my CASA cases. I have been humiliated, which I am sure was the Supt.'s goal.  Can anything be done?

Comment: Were you a student, faculty, unaffiliated volunteer or something else?  And if you were a student, how old were you at the time?

Unless you are a student in mandatory education, you may not have any right to be on school property should they not want you there - in that situation, trespass is the way to remove you from the property.

I'm less convinced of the first amendment argument here, hence the queries.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "a book that I had released and my advocacy work that resulted in the system being taken to court"? That might help you get a more helpful answer.

Comment: We cannot advise what a [\oerson should do in  a particular situation. We can answer questions about what the law permits or requires. I suggest that you rewrite the question to ask abut the relevant law. In any case you will probably need a lawyer to go forward with this.

Comment: If the teacher gave you permission to be at the school then I would suppose you were not trespassing *at that time*.  But the "trespass" stuff is often used as shorthand for a formal warning that you *no longer* have permission, that you need to leave immediately, and that if you come back *then* you will be trespassing and liable to be arrested, etc.

Answer (score -4):

You may have a claim for First Amendment retaliation, which could entitle you to monetary damages and order compelling the school to lift the trespass order.

You should talk to a lawyer with experience in this area of the law.

Comment: On what basis is the First Amendment claim? I am assuming the OP is an adult, so not a student, so no right to education at the school. Just because it is a government building does not mean that anyone can be there anytime.

Comment: The fact that the school wasn't required to let her on the premises is irrelevant. It extended her that privilege and then revoked it because she engaged in First Amendment-protected activity, i.e., writing a book and pursuing court action.

Comment: No, sorry. They can invite and dis-invite her at will. They can invite her once and not again, she can't just keep showing up forever. The principal can overrule the teacher's invitation and central can overrule the principal. Anyway, go prove that it is because of the book and not just a vague "this mentoring program does not meet our needs."

Comment: That's a very interesting theory. I don't suppose you could point to a law that permits a government agency to punish people for exercising their First Amendment rights?

Comment: I'd likewise be interested in hearing which other privileges the government could revoke 
because OP wrote a book. Can it suspend OP's driver's license? Business licenses? Could it fine OP for writing a book? Is there any limit on how many years it could send OP to prison for writing a book?

Comment: This unaffiliated person has no right to be at the school during school hours at all. It is nothing like a drivers license, business license, use of the library. And no one is sending anyone to prison. these are all non-sequiturs.

Comment: That's more of a random assertion than a statement of law. Can you point to any law that permits a government agency to punish people for exercising their First Amendment rights?

Comment: Here is the  Gwinnet County (chose a random county in Georgia) policy.https://www.gcpsk12.org/Page/23791 (Go to K, then Visitors to Schools) Can you point to any law that says a public school has to let anyone (non-student)  who wants in? There is no punishment because nothing is being taken away. She can stand on the sidewalk off school grounds and say whatever she wants. You have this assertion that denying her access- which is at the administrator's discretion- is a violation of 1st amendment rights. Can you show any case law that backs up that assertion?

Comment: I can of course point to law to support my answer. It would be rather silly for me to just spout off on the law if I didn't know what I was talking about. I'd recommend you start with  [*Elrod v. Burns*, 427 U.S. 347 (1976)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/427/347/) ("This Court's decisions have prohibited conditions on public benefits, in the form of jobs or otherwise, which dampen the exercise generally of First Amendment rights, however slight the inducement to the individual to forsake those rights.").

Comment: The crucial point you're missing is that something *is* being taken away. The school invited OP onto the district's property, and then it took away that invitation. An administrator may exercise discretion to decide who is permitted on school property, but the First Amendment prohibits exercising that discretion to punish people for protected speech, just like the Fourteenth Amendment prohibits exercising it to exclude black people.

Comment: Thank you. This will be my last comment. Entering a school as a non-student or parent, even being a volunteer mentor, is not the same as employment (Re: Elrod v Burns) And it is not a public benefit.

Comment: Yes, volunteering is quite different from being employed, though the difference is immaterial. I'm glad I was able to persuade you. For anyone looking for law outside of the employment context, I'd also recommend  [*Rosenberger v. University of Va.*, 515 U.S. 819 (1995)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supct/html/94-329.ZO.html) ("Once it has opened a limited forum, however, the State must respect the lawful boundaries it has itself set. The State may not ... discriminate against speech on the basis of its viewpoint.")

Comment: The book advocated pedophilia and the school decided that its author would not be an appropriate person to interact with the students under their care. Tell me more about the absolute nature of the 1st amendment

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I'm pretty sure you're just making that up, but OK.

Comment: Yes, I made it up to demonstrate the flaw in your position.

Comment: You've certainly identified a flaw in a position that no one has actually taken. Not a particularly useful way to spend your time, but I guess it could be rewarding for certain people.